# How to add Android emulators to VS code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, command-line, android-emulator

When I use `flutter run` command it shows the following message:

```
Multiple devices found:
Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 88.0.4324.146
Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 86.0.622.51
[1]: Chrome (chrome)
[2]: Edge (edge)
Please choose one (To quit, press "q/Q"):
```

Also this is the result of  `flutter emulators` command:

```
3 available emulators:

Nexus_5x       • Nexus_5x       • Google • android
Pixel_2_API_29 • Pixel 2 API 29 • Google • android
pixel_xl       • pixel_xl       • Google • android

To run an emulator, run 'flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>'.
To create a new emulator, run 'flutter emulators --create [--name xyz]'.

You can find more information on managing emulators at the links below:
  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds
  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager
```

Is it possible to add Android emulators to the list of `flutter run` command beside chrome and edge browsers?

Comment: Try `flutter run -d pixel_xl`. Or create a debug configuration.

Answer (score 6):

You should:

- Retrieve the list of the available emulators

```
flutter emulators
```

- Launch the emulator

```
flutter emulators --launch Nexus_5x
```

Then when you run `flutter run` you should see your new android emulator.

Answer (score 2):

- Download Android SDK and make initial setup.
- Relaunch VSCode and clean the project:

  ```
  flutter clean
  ```
- if this didn't help, try to update licences:

  ```
  flutter doctor --android-licenses
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The `flutter devices` command shows "available devices". Emulators that have not been started are not "available" until they've been started.

If you're using VS Code, you may find it better to use the built-in device management and debugging rather than using the terminal. In the status bar in the bottom right corner it should show your "active device" and if you click on it, it will let you switch to another device. That list shows emulators even if they're not started, and selecting one will automatically start it.

[image: Device/Emulator list]